# Maven: running Unit-Tests remotely

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, build-automation

We are currently working on a distributed Java EE-Application and have therefore a separated test and production system.

Compiling and Bundling is done via an Ant-Task. Now we want to deploy the Jar-Files of the different servers to the test-servers and run the JUnit Integration / Function-Tests there. If they succeed, then the current version should be deployed to the live-servers.

Plain Unit-Tests are executed by Hudson.
Is that possible with Maven and is there any information or best practice available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Hudson has maven integration. Take a loot this [wiki](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Building+a+maven2+project) and this [link](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2007/02/maven_2_integra.html).

You can set unit test case thresholds for your job to see if it does not pass a certain number of test cases. In that the deploy plugin will not get invoked and the app will not get deployed.

Comment: i'm looking for an automated functional testframework, that checks out from SCM, compiles the code, copies the jars to the different test servers, runs the unit and functional tests and copies them to the production system

Comment: That's exactly what hudson jobs do. Maven builds will automatically run the test cases as long as you them set up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a JAR built from Ant and reuse it.  I would add a Maven repository to your environment such as Artifactory, Archiva, or Nexus and deploy to that using Ivy.  You almost certainly need to use a Maven repository to be happy with Maven for anything other than small scale personal projects.  http://ant.apache.org/ivy/
2. Use Maven to grab the JAR from the Maven Repository.  For this, just use a normal Maven dependency declaration.
3. Run Maven on the QA server, with the JUnit tests declared in that project.  If that succeeds, deploy the JAR to the production server.  For this, the details depend on the production server.  If it's a WAR, I would use Cargo, but if it's a JAR it really depends on what's executing the JAR - you might need some sort of file copy, scp, etc. http://cargo.codehaus.org/

Hudson and TeamCity both have deployment features as well.  You just set up a job to run (in this case the Maven job) and tell the CI server to deploy on success.